# Define multiple word token and extract all tokens after the words with SpaCy Matcher

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am having some trouble understanding the SpaCy Matcher module.

I have a sentence: `I think this is great, but I would not do it again`

I would like to return the `but I would not do it again` text.

What I have so far is:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern = [{"LOWER": "but"}]
doc = nlp("I think this is great, but I would not do it again")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print(span.text)
```

This code only returns `but`.

Furthermore, is it doable to create a list of strings for the pattern matches, such that:

```
list_of_match_words = ['but', 'particularly']
pattern = [{'LOWER'}: list_of_match_words}]
```

Or the like? I know that the above would not run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a [`REGEX`](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#regex) operator to match specific tokens of your choice, and then you may use `{"OP": "*"}` to get the rest of the tokens to the right of the matching token:

```
list_of_match_words = ['but', 'particularly']
pattern = [{"TEXT" : {"REGEX": "(?i)^(?:{})$".format("|".join(list_of_match_words))}}, {"OP": "*"}]
matcher.add("list_of_match_words", None, pattern)
```

Here, the regex will look like `(?i)^(?:but|particularly)$` matching

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode on
- `^` - start of string (here, token)
- `(?:but|particularly)` - a non-capturing group matching `but` or `particularly` strings
- `$` - end of string (here, token).

The `{"OP": "*"}` part matches any tokens, 0 or more times.

**Full spaCy snippet**:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
from itertools import *

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

list_of_match_words = ['but', 'particularly']
pattern = [{"TEXT" : {"REGEX": "(?i)^(?:{})$".format("|".join(list_of_match_words))}}, {"OP": "*"}]
matcher.add("list_of_match_words", None, pattern)
doc = nlp("I think this is great particularly, but I would not do it again")
matches = matcher(doc)
results = [max(list(group),key=lambda x: x[2]) for k, group in groupby(sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x[1]), lambda x: x[1])]
print("Matches:", [doc[start:end].text for match_id, start, end in results])
```

Output:

```
Matches: ['particularly, but I would not do it again', 'but I would not do it again']
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer -- I was looking at how to extract the full sentence after that specific word? Is that do-able?

Comment: @JOKKINATOR What is your expected output for `list_of_match_words = ['but', 'particularly']` and `"I think this is great particularly, but I would not do it again"` text?

Comment: "but I would not do it again"

Comment: @JOKKINATOR Why? Why not `['particularly, but I would not do it again', 'but I would not do it again']`?

Comment: Your output is exactly what I expected, I was wrong. Of course.